# How to append output in bash?

Tags: bash, append

I have a shell command that produces line based output. Let me call it `magic` for the sake of the argument. For whatever output it produces, how can I just append another value to it? I would like to do it in a pipe. I tried for a long time to google this without any luck. It seems like I must be missing some obvious way to do it. Ideally, there would be another unix command called `append` which given as standard input the output of any other command the same output along with its arguments.

What I am imagining:

> magic

This returns:

```
apple
cherry
banana
```

> magic | append taro

This returns:

```
apple
cherry
banana
taro
```

Does this `append` command already exist with a different name? If so, what is it called?

Comment: Use `{ magic; echo 'taro'; }`

Comment: That's probably what I am looking for. Can you submit as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may use grouping of command using `{ ...; }` to group multiple commands:

```sh
{ magic; echo 'taro'; }
```

And if you want to redirect output to a file then use:

```sh
{ magic; echo 'taro'; } > outfile
```

Comment: Until I have seen this, I had no idea how bash functions worked.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is not to use a pipe, but anubhava's `{ magic; echo 'taro'; }`.

However, since you asked a pipe, you've opened up Pandora's box of possibilities.

```
magic|sed '$ataro'
```

is the first.

```
magic| awk '{print} END{print "taro"}'
```

as second.

Or a bash function:

```
hop(){
    while read line; do
        echo $line
    done
    echo $1
}

magic | hop taro
```

And so on.